# get 'Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid range in character class' when loading the Dymo SDK offline

Tags: javascript, html, dymo

The script loaded online working perfectly. The program will be used offline so i load the dymo sdk script offline. i copied/paste the response to the request

```
https://s3.amazonaws.com/download.dymo.com/dymo/Software/JavaScript/dymo.connect.framework.js
```

in a file called `dymo.connect.framework.js` in the main folder

when i load the script from `<script src="dymo.connect.framework.js"></script>` in the main html file, i get a error `Uncaught SyntaxError: invalid range in character class` to the line `goog.i18n.bidi.rtlCharReg_ = new RegExp('[' + goog.i18n.bidi.rtlChars_ + ']'),`

i don't understand why the error appear only offline.